# Keycloak: How to customize user email to be mandatory and immutable

Tags: keycloak

Our old authentication mechanism had mandatory and immutable email for each user by design. After exporting old authentincation mechanism into the hands of Keycloak 4.6.Final, We are left with old references to users by email as this was in fact used as an id from the beginning of this system.
Keycloak User Management UI is delivered to client as part of a whole system. Now we're facing a problem where the users administrator at the customer's side is able to create users with no email, and even worst, he give a user one email and overtime change it. Leaving this option open is most likely to create bugs for the client as the user base grows.

I've been digging around google, sof, keycloak mailing list search engine, and couldn't find any documentation relating developer's ability to apply configuration on top of particular keycloak distribution which would set features such as mandatory and immutable on some user attributes which are optional and editable by default.

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is old, but maybe someone will need answer.
it's 2022-11 and there is experimentas feature in Keycloak 20. You can enable declarative-user-profile and then customize your user profile and set required fields and other options. [user-profile](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#user-profile)

This feature may be removed in the future, because it's experimental.
And this feature has bugs (tried with 20.0.1). For example, if you add required attribute group, then you can see groups while creating new user and you can select groups. But if you try to save user, then error appears telling, that group is required.